# Отправка POST запроса без перезагрузки страницы.

Tags: php, ajax

Как возможно и возможно ли вообще реализовать отправка POST запроса без перезагрузки страницы не подключая Ajax и jQuery?

Comment: Разобрались бы сначала что такое AJAX и что такое jQuery... А то вопрос походит смыслом на "Возможно ли выкопать яму не используя копание ямы и бульдозер?"

Comment: Ну веть было время когда небыло ни  Ajax ни jQuery но строници работали без перезагрузки!

Comment: Ага, когда сайты были одностраничные)

Comment: Сайты начали работать без перезагрузки только с появлением Ajax?

Comment: @Kirpich643, гляньте [вот тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). Может всё читать и не надо, но пару абзацев в разделе "История" - почитатайте.

Comment: А что означает класическая модель веб-приложения?

Comment: @Kirpich643, Там же это, в прямом смысле, вам в картинках расписали.

Comment: Нет я конечно понимаю вечер, но до меня совсем туго доходит. Получается класическая модель веб-приложения работоет с перезагрузкой?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<iframe name="iframe1" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;"></iframe>
<form method="POST" action="/handler/" target="iframe1">...</form>
```

Comment: Только не обязательно скрывать таким образом. Достаточно **display: none;**

Comment: Я чтото не совсем понимаю что значит action="/handler/" и что означает для формы target="iframe1"?

и если можно пример: 
предположим что есть форма
 <form action="handler.php">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
как отправит её содержимое на сервер без перезагрузки строници и получить ответ?

Comment: <iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;"></iframe>
    <form action="handler.php" target="iframe1"> 
        <input type="text" name="name"> 
        <input type="submit"> 
    </form>

    // пытаемся достучаться до iframe
    var fr = document.getElementById('iframe1');
    var fw = (fr.contentWindow || fr.contentDocument);
    if ( !!!fw.document) fw = fw.defaultView;

    if ( fw ) // fw - это объект window ифрейма
    // ломай его полностью. Как хочешь (почти)

Comment: А что означает :
var fw = (fr.contentWindow || fr.contentDocument);
if ( !!!fw.document) fw = fw.defaultView;

Comment: это попытка доступа к внутренностям ифрейма. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще один забавный способ делать ajax без, собственно, ajax-а. Метод заключается в создании тега <script> в хедере документа:

```
// Загружает и выполняет переданный JavaScript по ссылке
function load_js(js_url, js_id) {
    if (js_id == undefined) js_id = 'some_js_script';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = js_id;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    uniq_string = js_id + cdt_uniq_string();
    if (js_url.indexOf("?") > 0) delim = '&'; else delim = '?';
    script.src = js_url + delim + uniq_string;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
};

// Рандомная строка, используется для добавления к ссылке на JS, чтобы браузер не кешировал ее
function cdt_uniq_string() { return Math.random().toString().replace(/\./g,""); };

def some_callback(arguments) { alert(arguments) }
```

Смысл в том, что серверу вместе с запросом javascript-а, в ссылке передаются нужные параметры, он их как-то обрабатывает и отдает валидный джаваскрипт в виде строки вроде:

```
some_callback('string from server!');
```

В результате браузер передает серверу некоторые параметры и взамен получает некоторые данные в функцию some_callback, что и нужно от аякса. Этот метод используется, например, для кроссдоменного аякса.

Answer (score 1):

Не подключая Ajax и jQuery? - Про jQuery ладно, а зачем подключать Ajax? JS без всяких библиотек позволяет использовать Ajax. Там лишь некоторые затруднения для кросбраузерности, но это легко гуглится, готовый код там строк на 10. Ну можно и самому написать. И используйте его не подключая ничего вообще.

Answer (score 1):

**Ajax'ом**. Во-первых нужно собрать данные с формы, во вторых отправить эту форму пост-запросом.
Удобнее всего как раз таки для этого использовать jQuery, но делать это не обязательно, можно самому написать весь код, который требуется для такого запроса (**google**: *AJAX запросы на нативном JS*).

Второй вариант — **поместить форму в iframe**, тогда, при нажатии на сабмит перезагрузится только iframe, а не все страница.

Answer (score 0):

Мне в голову сейчас приходит только периодическое посылаете с клиента Ajax запросов на сервер. Но я думаю, что можно и проталкивание с сервера сделать с помощью сокетов

Answer (score 0):

Вот я недавно писал код но тут GET

```
function jsonp(url) {
    var head = document.head;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    head.appendChild(script);
    head.removeChild(script);
}

function jsonpCallbac(data) {
   console.log(data);
}

sendData.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var inputElements = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    formData = '?callback=jsonpCallbac';
    for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
        var inputData = inputElements[i];
        if(inputData.value.length > 0){
              formData += '&' + inputData.name + '=' + inputData.value;

        }
    }
    jsonp(url + formData);
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
    $callback = $_GET["callback"];
    $phone = $_GET["phone"];
    $json = "{\"status\":\"" . true . "\"}";
    echo $callback . "(" . $json . ")";
?>
```

Comment: Переделать ваше решение с GET на POST невозможно, к сожалению. Тем более, вы используете JSONP, что также все сильно упрощает.